# Find person with most recent trade by group

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that lists groups where a trade was made with each group (trader = person).

```
Group, Person, Date
Group A, Person 1, 2021-03-04
Group A, Person 2, 2021-03-03
Group A, Person 3, 2021-03-02
Group B, Person 1, 2021-02-03
Group B, Person 2, 2021-02-02
Group B, Person 3, 2021-02-01
```

I want to find the person that made the latest trade by group. So ideally, the table would look like:

```
Group, Person, Date
Group A, Person 1, 2021-03-04
Group B, Person 1, 2021-02-03
```

I've come across various formulas for Excel ( e.g. INDEX(range1,MATCH(MAX(range2),range2,0)) and {=INDEX(range1,MATCH(1,(A1=range2)*(B1=range3)*(C1=range4),0))} ), but I can't find a way or method that would combine these two formulas together and create what I need.

Answer (score 3):

If one has Microsoft365:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=FILTER(A2:C7,C2:C7=MAXIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,A2:A7))
```

Comment: Neat - but what does *(A2:A7=A2:A7) do? Isn't it always true?

Comment: @TomSharpe, you are right, it can be ignored =)

Comment: Very cool! But what if I don't have 365? haha

Comment: @JamesR. there is always a reasonable easy solution when you could get away with a helper column and using a proper filter on your data.

Answer (score 1):

Without O365, you could

- create a list of the groups in, for example `H24:Hnn`
- Note that I inserted a **Table** and am using structured references. But you could use regular addressing if you must.  *I find tables easier to use and maintain for a variety of reasons*

```
    Person: I24: =INDEX(IF((MAX(IF(tblTrades[Group]=H24,tblTrades[Date]))=tblTrades[Date])*(H24=tblTrades[Group]),tblTrades[Person],""),1)
    Date:   J24: =MAX(IF(H24=tblTrades[Group],tblTrades[Date]))
```

and fill down as far as required.

[image]

You could also do this fairly easily with Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and O365)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a Pivot Table, fields `Group` and `Person` into Rows Section. Field `Date` into Values section. Make sure `Date` field is set to sum up values, and date format.

Then filter by TOP 10 in field `Person` and Choose 1 instead of 10, based on field `Sum of date`.

This will autofilter the table to show the Person with the highest date (highest = latest) in each group.

[image]

Sorry about the quality, had to compress to upload to SO